# Why has my Table been set to read only after running this transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Screenshot of Read Only marking on table]

I ran the transaction below because I wanted to insert values from a table called RoughworkIndirectFlights into a table called RoughworkPriceTable.

**This transaction did not work**. However after running it the RoughworkPriceTable has become set to **Read Only.**

Can anyone explain why this has happened and how can I change the table to become editable.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.RoughworkPriceTable ON;

    Declare @TransactionName varchar(50) = 'MergeTransaction';
    Begin Tran @TransactionName

    Merge RoughworkPriceTable AS p
    Using RoughworkIndirectFlights As i
    On p.ID = i.ID
    When Matched Then Update 
                      Set p.Airport_ICAO_Code=i.Airport_ICAO_Code,
                          p.Airline_ICAO_Code=i.Airline_ICAO_Code,
                          p.RouteStatus=i.RouteStatus
    When Not Matched By Target Then Insert(ID,Airport_ICAO_Code,Airline_ICAO_Code,RouteStatus)
                                    Values(i.ID,i.Airport_ICAO_Code,i.Airline_ICAO_Code,i.RouteStatus)
                                    Output $action, Inserted.*,Deleted.*;
```

Comment: You have to commit or rollback the transaction. You will probably also want to set identity insert off again.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you tell me how to commit the transaction and how to Rollback the transaction.

Comment: COMMIT TransactionName or ROLLBACK TransactionName

Comment: Do I add those to the existing code or do i write a new script

Comment: Same script, at the bottom. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx)

Comment: What makes you think it's read only? an error message? what is it it?

Comment: @Nick McDermaid it is because a transaction is pending and no changes can happen until a commit or rollback.

Comment: I added Commit transaction to the code and ran it again. the data was inserted correctly. however the table is still marked as read only.The red only mark is on the bottom of the table. I will insert a screenshot into my post if stackoverflow allows it to show this.

Comment: I have added screenshot to my post showing the read only marking. its at the bottom of the table. The Ids in the range from 5000000 are the new values that were entered.

Comment: I think ive found the answer. the cells in the ID column are marked as read only but not the other cells. I should have set the Identity Insert to OFF at the end of the code. Now that the code has ran can I set the Idenity Insert to OFF using a seperate script or will I have to rollback the transaction

Comment: Yes... it pays to explain the full story first before we jump to incorrect conclusions.

Comment: Sachin has answered the rolllback Qs below. Thanks to all for taking the time to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that only `ID` column is read-only and I believe that `ID` column is an `Identity` column in your table. If that's the case then this behavior is expected. As the value of Identity column is `auto-incremented` and you can't set the value of that, that's why that `ID` column is read-only. I hope you are able to change the value in other columns.

Comment: Thanks Sachin. You are correct.Im just after posting a comment under the original post saying the same thing. the cells in the ID column are marked as read only but not the other cells. I should have set the Identity Insert to OFF at the end of the code. Now that the code has ran can I set the Idenity Insert to OFF using a seperate script or will I have to rollback the transaction –

Comment: No you don't need to rollback the transaction. You can simple use the `set identity_insert YourTable ON` to allow the insertion of value in the `ID` column.

Comment: Thnaks very much Sachin. youve been a great help